# Typescript React How to declare json object in interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a JSON like this:

```
data: {
  title: "cool video",
  director: "ALI",
  release_date: "1977-05-25",
  customer: {
    id: "abc"
  }, 
  student: {
    id: "123"

  }, 
  vendors: {
    id: "123adc"
  }
}
```

I wish to make it into an `interface` of the react component

What I got so far:

```
export interface storeBioFormProps {
    title: string;
    director: string;
    release_date: string;

    //NOTE: How can I declare the customer, student and vendors here?
}

export const StoreBioForm: React.FC<storeBioFormProps> = () => {
    return (
       <div>
           
       </div>
    );
}
```

As I can see, I able to declare the `title`, `director` and `release_date`(which is only a string) into the `interface` named `storeBioFormProps`.

**Problem:**

But the value of `customer`, `vendors` and `student` which is a json object, then I dont know how to declare it into `storeBioFormProps`.

**I tried like**:

```
export interface storeBioFormProps {
   title: string;
   director: string;
   release_date: string;

   customer: customerData;
   student: studentData;
   vendor: vendorData;
}

interface customerData {
    id: string;
}

interface studentData {
    id: string;
}

interface vendorData {
    id: string;
}
```

I new to Typescript, is this the correct way to do that?

**Question:**

How can I include `customer`, `vendors` and `student` into `storeBioFormProps`?

Comment: Your "I tried like:" is how I would do it, there are other ways, but that's the most flexible one I'm aware of.

Comment: @DBS nice, thanks for confirmation. Just getting started in typescript, so is very nice to to get some validation

Comment: If customers, students and vendors will always be the same, you could make it a bit shorter: `interface idField = {id: string}` and then `customer: idField, student: idField, ...` - otherwise yours is a correct approach.

Comment: @Taxel I see, learnt something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout these two ways:
First: inline

```
interface storeBioFormProps {
  title: string,
  director: string,
  release_date: string,
  customer: {
    id: string
  }, 
  student: {
    id: string

  }, 
  vendors: {
    id: string
  }
}
```

Second: separate

```
interface storeBioFormProps {
  title: string,
  director: string,
  release_date: string,
  customer: CustomerProps, 
  student: StudentProps,, 
  vendors:  VendorProps
}

interface CustomerProps {
  id: string
}

interface StudentProps {
  id: string
}

interface VendorProps {
  id: string
}
```